# R Data.table datetime variable into separate variable with IDate.Time

Tags: r, string, datetime, data.table

I have a datetime variable (`vardt`) as a string in data table. 
E.g. `"21/07/2011 15:54:57"`

I want to split the date and the time into different variables. I can do it fast with the following code.

```
DT <- DT[,"time":= substr(vardt,12,19)]
DT <- DT[,"date":= substr(vardt,1,10)]
```

However, when I try to put the variable into a POSIX format, it crashes.

```
DT <- DT[,"date":= as.IDate(substr(vardt,1,10))]
```

I need POSIX format in order to subset all the observations before a certain hour (e.g. before 10am). Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here? Any idea is welcome

*I have millions of observations so I really need efficiency.

Comment: It's more difficult to use the hours if you split the datetime.  You may want to keep it as one column and use `as.POSIXct()` and then you can use (some) mathematical methods on the result.  Or check out package `chron`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "it crashes" when you try `DT[,"date":= as.IDate(substr(vardt,1,10))]` - this did give me a column `date` of the class `IDate`; just not a properly formatted one:

```
                   vardt     date
  1: 24/01/2015 04:31:36 24-01-20
  2: 24/01/2015 09:19:36 24-01-20
  3: 23/01/2015 17:29:36 23-01-20
  4: 24/01/2015 01:25:36 24-01-20
  5: 24/01/2015 01:55:36 24-01-20
```

You can fix this by specifying the `format`:

```
DT[,date:=as.IDate(substr(vardt,1,10),"%d/%m/%Y")]
DT[,time:=as.ITime(substr(vardt,12,19))]

R>  DT
                   vardt       date     time
  1: 24/01/2015 04:31:36 2015-01-24 04:31:36
  2: 24/01/2015 09:19:36 2015-01-24 09:19:36
  3: 23/01/2015 17:29:36 2015-01-23 17:29:36
  4: 24/01/2015 01:25:36 2015-01-24 01:25:36
  5: 24/01/2015 01:55:36 2015-01-24 01:55:36
 ---                                        
 97: 23/01/2015 15:55:36 2015-01-23 15:55:36
 98: 23/01/2015 23:06:36 2015-01-23 23:06:36
 99: 24/01/2015 10:29:36 2015-01-24 10:29:36
100: 23/01/2015 23:07:36 2015-01-23 23:07:36
101: 24/01/2015 01:27:36 2015-01-24 01:27:36
```

Then you can use the `hour` function to proceed however you wish, e.g.

```
R>  head(DT[hour(time)<10,])
                 vardt       date     time
1: 24/01/2015 04:31:36 2015-01-24 04:31:36
2: 24/01/2015 09:19:36 2015-01-24 09:19:36
3: 24/01/2015 01:25:36 2015-01-24 01:25:36
4: 24/01/2015 01:55:36 2015-01-24 01:55:36
5: 24/01/2015 04:10:36 2015-01-24 04:10:36
6: 24/01/2015 01:51:36 2015-01-24 01:51:36
```

or

```
R>  DT[,.(Freq=.N),by=hour(time)][order(hour)]
    hour Freq
 1:    0    2
 2:    1   10
 3:    2    4
 4:    3    3
 5:    4    2
 6:    5    1
 7:    6    3
 8:    7    1
 9:    8    6
10:    9    4
11:   10    3
12:   11    3
13:   12    6
14:   13    3
15:   14    4
16:   15    8
17:   16    3
18:   17    6
19:   18    2
20:   19    7
21:   20    5
22:   21    7
23:   22    5
24:   23    3
```

Also note that when you are assigning / modifying by reference with `:=`, you don't have to reassign the object to itself - so instead of `DT <- DT[,newCol:="xyz"]`, you can just do `DT[,newCol:="xyz"]`.

---

**Data:**

```
x <- Sys.time()+sample(seq(0,24*3600,60),101,TRUE)
##
x <- gsub(
  "(\\d+)\\-(\\d+)\\-(\\d+)",
  "\\3/\\2/\\1",
  x)
##
DT <- data.table(vardt=x)
```

Answer (score -1):

try strsplit(column_name, "  ")